# How to use php code in javascript alert in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, alert

I am using this code in my controller and it's not working, showing parse error.
Can you guys please help me out.

```
 echo "<script>
        alert("<?php echo $v[$keys[$i+4]],"is going out of stock"; ?>");
</script>" ;
```

Thank you!

Comment: include your error message.`$v[$keys[$i+4]],"is going out of stock"` should be `$v[$keys[$i+4]]."is going out of stock"` dot not comma

Comment: don't use `alert` it locks the browser, use a modal overlay or other form of notification like a growl

Comment: i've tried, but it's not working. It is showing parse error

Comment: Try to avoid spaghetti code, separe in different layers javascript from controller, you should at least put it inside some view, never in the controller, it brokes the mvc pattern

Comment: thanks @cmorrissey n #Balder for suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not concatenating the static text correctly. Try this:

```
echo "<script>
    alert('" . $v[$keys[$i+4]] . " is going out of stock.');
</script>" ;
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel . It has run successfully :)